# sqlite opening db: './sqlite.db': permission denied

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, sqlite, tomcat

I'm making a restful application using Jersey, I'm using Hibernate to manage the persistence layer of my web service, currently I was using Postgresql, but now I want to change Postgresql to embedded SQLite, but I get the following error on initialize:

```
1    [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: opening db: './sqlite.db': Acceso denegado
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:203)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at foo.Mediator.initialize(Mediator.java:55)
    at foo.listeners.ResourceManagerListener.contextInitialized(ResourceManagerListener.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
117  [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - opening db: './sqlite.db': Acceso denegado
```

I'm trying to create `sqlite.db` but the permission is denied. Any clue to how resolve this?

PD: This is persistence.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:./sqlite.db</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">foo.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
    <!-- Update the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="config/Mapping.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

PD2: My SQLiteDialect:

```
package foo;

import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.function.AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.NoArgSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "boolean");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric($p, $s)");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar($l)");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");

        registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", ""));
        registerFunction("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2"));
        registerFunction("quote", new StandardSQLFunction("quote", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        registerFunction("random", new NoArgSQLFunction("random", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
        registerFunction("round", new StandardSQLFunction("round"));
        registerFunction("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        registerFunction("substring", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "substr(?1, ?2, ?3)"));
        registerFunction("trim", new AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction() {
            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFromFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingSpaceTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveBothTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1, ?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1, ?2)");
            }

            protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingTrimFunction() {
                return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1, ?2)");
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query).append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?")
            .toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName, String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable,
        String[] primaryKey, boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsTupleDistinctCounts() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getSelectGUIDString() {
        return "select hex(randomblob(16))";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found that when the persistence.cfg.xml has:
 `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:./sqlite.db</property>`

The route selected by the sqlite is the next one: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\.\sqlite.db`and obviously has no permission to access there...

Comment: Use a directory your program has permission to write to for the database. Whatever its current working directory is obviously isn't one.

Comment: My current directory have all the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The problem was due to I was running the Tomcat inside Eclipse, and by default it shows the C:\WINDOWS\system32 , When I run the web service in a Tomcat outside of Eclipse works perfectly.